# Flutter - Execution failed for task ':unique_identifier:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I get this when I do 'flutter run --release'

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unique_identifier:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\df6cf23cc51da578d8b158de17d0c9cb\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\df6cf23cc51da578d8b158de17d0c9cb\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      19.7s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin camera...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    1.7s
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

When I do `flutter run --debug` I don't get this issue,

Any idea how to solve it?

I tried down grading `cloud_firestore` to `0.12.11` and `0.12.10+2` but it didn't help

I tried:

```
    minSdkVersion 29
    targetSdkVersion 29
```

it didn't help

I checked the file: `C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\df6cf23cc51da578d8b158de17d0c9cb\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml` and indeed the 2 mentioned items are missing, I try to add them manually but it is deleted when I run `flutter run --release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

After I did `flutter run --release --verbose`, I realize that `unique_identifier` was refering to the package `unique_identifier` that I have in my YAML file but not actually uses in the project.

So I removed `unique_identifier` and the build passed.

The message about `cloud_firestore` confused me, and is not really related.